# Setting Timezone Not working for second time in PHP

Tags: php, timezone

I am trying to deal with date time like below

```
$early_start = 1;
$delivery_start_time ="2022-01-02";

     if($early_start==1){
                  
         $seller_time_now = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));
          $seller_time_now = $seller_time_now->format('H.i');
                    
          echo  $delivery_start_time."<br>";
                    
          echo  $seller_time_now."<br>";
                    
           if($seller_time_now>=08.00 && $seller_time_now<=17.00){
    
             $delivery_start_deadline =  new DateTime("now");
             echo $delivery_start_deadline;
          }
            else{
              echo "Schedule for next day <br>";
              $seller_time_next_day = new DateTime($delivery_start_time." 08:00:00 +1day", new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata') );
              $seller_time_next_day =  $seller_time_next_day->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                        
              echo $seller_time_next_day."<br>";
                         
                         
              $delivery_start_deadline = new DateTime($seller_time_next_day, new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
             $delivery_start_deadline =  $delivery_start_deadline->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                        
                       
             echo $delivery_start_deadline."<br>";
                        
            }
                    
  }
```

But its giving me output like below

```
2022-01-02
18.57
Schedule for next day
2022-01-03 08:00:00
2022-01-03 08:00:00
```

since `$seller_time_next_day is 2022-01-03 08:00:00 for india timezone`, When I use New York timezone, `its still giving me exact same time for $delivery_start_deadline`. I think I am doing something wrong, I am trying from hour but not getting idea whats wrong with my logic, let me know if someone here can help me for solve the puzzle. Thanks!

Comment: you're doing a lot of weird things in this code, but the main one is that you have the wrong conception of what a `DateTime` represents. Start by changing your `->format` lines to `->format('Y-m-d H:i:s p');` so you can see the actual result of your actions.

Comment: @Raxi Now its output is 2022-01-03 08:00:00 p for both

Comment: Use `date_timezone_set`  (DateTime::setTimezone) when switching timezone . See [official_documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php)

Comment: Ah, you have an older version of php then; use `O` instead of `p` in that case

Comment: @Raxi now its 2022-01-03 08:00:00 +0530 for both echo

Comment: its look like setting America/New_York is not taking effect!

Comment: @KenLee its worked fine with your solution. Thanks!

Comment: Yes and no. You just have a faulty view of what you're dealing with, you should really read the documentation on `DateTime` because its a big subject with lots of nuance. The subject is really way too big to touch on in comments here. But the TZ used when creating a DateTime object is a separate thing from the presentation of a datetime in a certain TZ.